# My link image has invisible pixels that I want to remove via coding

Tags: php, css, image, button, hyperlink

My image link has "invisible pixels" that show up as a link when you hover above the actual image. Is there any way to remove them? Here is my code:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="navbuttonbox">

        <a href="Movies.php"><img src="img/test.png"/></a>

    </div>
</div><!--sidebar-->
```

For the style I use

```
#navbuttonbox {
    margin-left: 37px;
}
```

So that It will be right where I want it.

I demonstrated it on JSFIDDLE
https://jsfiddle.net/1g2pqwy2/1/

When you move your mouse a little bit above the image you still get a cursor link because the tail of the image is higher then the body.

Comment: OK, here is a quick try - `#navbuttonbox img {display:block;}`, see if that helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No you cannot detect when the mouse cursor is over the transparent part of an image... if thats what you mean

Comment: Did you know accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First here is your HTML.

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="navbuttonbox">
        <a href="Movies.php"><img src="img/test.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="navbuttonbox">
    <a href="Movies.php">Movies</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbuttonbox">
    <a href="OTHER.PHP">OTHER</a>
    </div> <!--- KEEP REPEATING FOR EACH MENU ITEM //-->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbuttonbox {
  position:relative;
  background: url(/img/test.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-right: -38px;
}

.navbuttonbox > a {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
}
```

You'll notice the link is shifted down for those invisible pixels.  The tail can be fixed too if you need it with:

```
.navbuttonbox > a:before {
  content:'';
  width:38px;
  top:-10px;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  position:absolute;
}
```

To demonstrate I set up a JSFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmx7w2ns/1/)